# Merging two xml nodes with same path and printing their sum

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I need help regarding one of the logic wrt to xmls. I have four nodes like below:

```
<Root>
<Element>
<ElementId>Fruits</ElementId>
<ElementDes>Apple</ElementDes>
<ElementValue>100</ElementValue>
</Element>
<Element>
<ElementId>Fruits</ElementId>
<ElementDes>Mango</ElementDes>
<ElementValue>200</ElementValue>
</Element>
<ElementId>Vegetables</ElementId>
<ElementDes>Potato</ElementDes>
<ElementValue>300</ElementValue>
</Element>
<Element>
<ElementId>Vegetables</ElementId>
<ElementDes>Brinjal</ElementDes>
<ElementValue>400</ElementValue>
</Element>
</Root>
```

I need output as below:(Sum of the same type of Element Ids):

```
<Root>
<Element>
<ElementId>Fruits</ElementId>
<ElementDes>AppleMango</ElementDes>
<ElementValue>300</ElementValue>
</Element>
<ElementId>Vegetables</ElementId>
<ElementDes>PotatoBrinjal</ElementDes>
<ElementValue>700</ElementValue>
</Element>
</Root>
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: There are a lot of frameworks for working with xml in Java. For example: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/index.html

Comment: See https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#grouping-examples for an XSLT 2.0 approach. You can use XSLT 2.0 with Java with Saxon 9.

Comment: Well, the tags already suggest he is using XSLT @mrbela :-)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your input data would be valid XML (your example is not), this would produce the expected result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="Root">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:for-each-group select="Element" group-by="ElementId">
            <Element>
               <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | ElementId"/>
               <ElementDes><xsl:value-of select="current-group()/ElementDes" separator=""/></ElementDes>
               <ElementValue><xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/ElementValue)"/></ElementValue>
            </Element>
         </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response will try out! :)